# Choosing Distortion Measures for Decision Rules with Logarithmic Posteriors

Tags: bayesian, loss-functions, posterior

I've been delving into Bayesian decision theory and specifically looking at scenarios where we work with the logarithm of the posterior distribution (log-posterior). My understanding is that in such cases, the decision-making process often involves selecting actions or hypotheses that minimize some form of expected loss or distortion, given the observed data.

However, I'm curious about what constitutes common or effective distortion measures when dealing with log-posteriors. Specifically, how do these measures influence the derivation of decision rules in practical Bayesian analysis?

From what I've gathered, several loss functions can be applied, each leading to different decision rules:

1. **Squared Error Loss**: Typically used in regression, where the decision rule aims at the mean of the posterior distribution.
2. **Absolute Error Loss**: Also used in regression, leading to the median of the posterior as the decision rule.
3. **0-1 Loss**: Common in classification, where the decision is based on the class with the highest posterior probability.
4. **Log Loss (Cross-Entropy Loss)**: Particularly relevant for log-posteriors, focusing on maximizing the posterior probability of the correct decision.

What I'm trying to understand is how these loss functions, especially the log loss, are practically applied when the posterior is expressed in logarithmic form. How does one go about formulating decision rules that minimize these expected losses? Are there any preferred practices or considerations to bear in mind, especially in terms of computational efficiency or analytical convenience?

Any insights or references to further reading would be greatly appreciated, especially those that delve into the nuances of applying these principles in real-world Bayesian analysis.